# Upload large csv file in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, file-upload, localhost, large-files

I am coding an upload page with flask for a large (200 MB) csv file. still the local run of this simple code wouldnt go further than the line request.files:
and the run will stuck in this level, how to solve the problem?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     print("first flag")
     if 'file1' not in request.files:
         return redirect(request.url)
     print("SECOND flag")  
     file1 = request.files['file1']
     print("third flag")  
     file2 = request.files['file2']
     print("forth flag")
```

the console will only print "first flag" meaning the if block is stuck!!!!!